# Can't upload file in IE 8-10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, rest, file-upload, simple-form

I'm using rails simple_form gem as my form builder. This form is working ok with all brousers except IE.

When form is submited with empty file input, it's submits OK. But when I chose some file in file input, form submition fails on timeout. In other worlds it looks like form isn't submited, IE simply isn't sending anything.

This is builded form

```
<form id="edit_user_29" class="simple_form form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/signup_wizard/user_info" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
.....
    <input id="user_avatar" class="file optional" type="file" name="user[avatar]">
```

This is my simple form

```
= simple_form_for(@user, url: wizard_path, :method => :put, :html: { multipart: true }) do |f|

  = f.input :avatar, label: 'Upload Photo'
```

A have added developer tool to my IE, and in the "Network tab" I see this output when the form is submited:

```
Method - (Pending...), Result - (Pending...), Type - (Pending...), Taken - (Pending...), Received - (Pending...)
```

Problem is the same even if I turn off all my Javascript.